# Generate Random Symmetric Weighted Adjacency Matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to test implementations of Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm by using a cost adjacency matrix. I'm generating these matrices on the amount of vertices in the graph, and the amount of edges in the graph. It does not have to be a connected graph.

Here's what I have so far:

```
final static int infinity = 2000000000;
public static int[][] genAdjMat(int V, int E) {
    int[][] a = new int[V][V];
    int e = E;

    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        for(int j = i; j < V; j++) {
            if(i == j) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                if(Math.random() < 0.5 && e >= 0) {
                    int temp = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*e);
                    a[i][j] = temp;
                    a[j][i] = temp;
                    e--;        
                }
                else {
                    a[i][j] = infinity;
                    a[j][i] = infinity;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Right now, it generates a symmetric array but it doesn't use all the edges that I specify. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use up all the edges and still have them randomly placed throughout the matrix while maintaining symmetry.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Initialize an empty matrix and add `E` random edges.

Comment: Wow, I feel foolish. This is quite simple, thanks for giving me another way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

1. Generate the list of all possible undirected edges (`V * (V - 1) / 2` items).
2. Shuffle it.
3. Pick the first `E` edges.

Comment: This is a great way to solve it! I ended up going with a modified version of what I had, where I fill the graph first with the random weighted edges, then put in the infinities where the edges missed!

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward: just generate the edges independently.

```
Random random = new Random();
Set<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> edges = Sets.newHashSet();
for (int i=0; i<e; i++) {
    do {
        int xCoordinate = random.nextInt(V);
        int yCoordinate = random.nextInt(V);
    } while(!edges.add(xCoordinate, yCoordinate)); 
}
```

Now use the edges to put them in your matrix.

Alternatively (while iterating over the matrix), use the following probability function: `p(A[i,j] == 1) = (e - k) / (V^2 - (i * V + j))`. Where `k` is the number of already assigned edges. The point of this is - have a probability less then 1 while the number of entries that are remaining is still higher then the number of edges you have to assign, this becomes 1 when the number of edges you still have to assign is equal to remaining entries to iterate over.